# how to enable view state checkbox for non salesforce admin profile

Tags: user, viewstate

we have multiple user who's user licence is salesforce but profile is not system administration, profile's are different-different. i need to enable view state and development mode for particular user. when i go to that user(s) **no checkbox of development mode and show view state** present in Advance user settings

Answer (score 1):

There is [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_dev_mode.htm&type=5) about how to enable developer mode. Prerequisite is to have "Customize Application" for the user, to whom you want to enable developer mode (it is defining on profile or permission set levels)

Then

> 1. From your personal settings, enter Advanced User Details in the Quick Find box, then select Advanced User Details. No results? Enter
>      Personal Information in the Quick Find box, then select Personal
>      Information.
> 2. Click Edit.
> 3. Select the Development Mode checkbox.
> 4. Optionally, select the Show View State in Development Mode checkbox to enable the View State tab on the development footer. This tab is
>      useful for monitoring the performance of your Visualforce pages.
> 5. Click Save.